# Linux Scheduling: OS vs "virtual"

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, scheduling

How does one implement a multithreaded single process model in linux fedora under c where a single scheduler is used on a "main" core reading i/o availability (ex. tcp/ip, udp) then having a single-thread-per-core (started at init), the "execution thread", parse the data then update a small amount of info update to shared memory space (it is my understanding pthreads share data under a single process).

I beleive my options are:

Pthreads or the linux OS scheduler

I have a naive model in mind consisting of starting a certain number of these execution threads a single scheduler thread.

What is the best solution one could think when I know that I can use this sort of model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completing Benoit's answer, in order to communicate between your master and your worker threads, you could use conditional variable. The workers do something like:

```
while (true)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(workQueueMutex);
    while (workQueue.empty())
        pthread_cond_wait(workQueueCond, workQueueMutex);
    /* if we get were then (a) we have work (b) we hold workQueueMutex */
    work = pop(workQueue);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(workQueueMutex);
    /* do work */
}
```

and the master:

```
/* I/O received */
pthread_mutex_lock(workQueueMutex);
push(workQueue, work);
pthread_cond_signal(workQueueCond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(workQueueMutex);
```

This would wake up one idle work to immediately process the request. If no worker is available, the work will be dequeued and processed later.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the Linux scheduler is quite a tough work. I would just forget about it. Pthread is usually prefered. If I understand well, you want to have one core dedicated to the control plan, and a pool of other cores dedicated to the data plan processing? Then create a pool of threads from your master thread and setup core affinity for these slave threads with `pthread_setaffinity_np(...)`.

Indeed threads of a process share the same address-space, and global variables are accessible by any threads of that process.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you have a version of the [producer-consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) with a single consumer aggregating the results of `n` producers. This is a pretty standard problem, so I definitely think that `pthread` is more than enough for you. You don't need to go and mess around with the scheduler.

As one of the answer's states, a thread safe queue like the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212623/multiple-writer-thread-safe-queue-in-c) works nicely for this sort of issue. Your original idea of spawning a bunch of threads is a good idea. You seem to be worried that the ability of the threads to share global state will cause you problems. I don't think that this is an issue if you keep shared state to a minimum and use sane locking discipline. Sharing state is fine as long as you do so responsibly.

Finally, unless you *really* know what you're doing, I would advise against manually messing with thread affinity. Just spawn the threads and let the scheduler handle when and on what core a thread runs. The thing to optimize is the number of threads you use. One for each core may not actually be the fastest approach if other threads are running.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, this is more or less exactly what the posix `select` and linux specific `epoll` functions are for.